# Pass PHP variable to Javascript variable not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables

Hi Im trying to get this php variable to be passed to a javacript variable. First i have added my helper class which consists of many functions just return values and arrays.

```php
    <?php
        require "./scripts/imageHelper.php";
    
        $totalImages = countAllImages("unclaimed/");
        echo $totalImages;
    ?>
```

Then i have included my script at the bottom of the page as it is in a seperate js file that is not run until the page is ready.

```js
    $( document ).ready(function()
    {
        request_page(1);
    });
    
    function request_page(pn)
    {
        var total = "<?php echo $totalImages; ?>";
        console.log(total);
    }
```

then when i run the page i get the variable echoed correctly by php but the javascript console just echos out the php code.
[console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6z7Hl.png)

Comment: is that `var total = "<?php echo $totalImages; ?>";` in the PHP page or in a javascript (`.js` ) file? If that is in a js file it will not work as the PHP server is not expecting to parse and process PHP instructions within a javascript file.

Comment: var total is located in the .js file

Comment: move it out of the js file into the php page

Comment: i thought of that when you mentioned it and it worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

**you can use a cookie**

add this function in your js code

```
function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

and add this in your php code

```
function set_cookie($name,$value){
  $cookie_name = $name;
  $cookie_value = $value;
  setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
}
```

and example use :

in php :

```
<?php 
set_cookie("totalImages",$totalImages);
?>
```

in js file:

```
var total = getCookie("totalImages");
```

## or

add bottom code in head

```
<meta name="totalImages" content="<?php echo $totalImages;?>">
```

and get it with bottom code in js

```
var total = document.querySelector("meta[name='totalImages']").getAttribute("content");
```

## or

you can create **hidden span tag** in html

```
<span id='totalImages' style='display:none'><?php echo $totalImages;?></span>
```

[or]

```
<span id='totalImages' hidden><?php echo $totalImages;?></span>
```

and add in js file for get value :

```
var total = document.getElementById("totalImages").innerText;
```

> i'm Khaled Developer